# Key differences between using Google Maps Javascript API v3 and Android MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova

Is the MapView a lot faster? Are tiles preloaded?  I'm currently testing a PhoneGap application that uses the GoogleMaps Javascript API v3 and it's very slow to load.... any tips?

Answer (score 0):

MapView is going to be much faster.  It is compiled rather then interpreted javascript, the MapView downloads tiles and caches them and is optimized for the device.